# PHP Mysqli fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The MySQLi feature of PHP is great.

Prepared Statements are great for injecting parameters in a query.

However, if you use Statements, it seems you dont have access to the fetch_assoc feature anymore. You have to manually bind all your results. This mean my SQL query has to list all the fields, then I have to list all the variables in advance when getting the results (using bind_result). This can become very annoying and time-wasting.

Is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLi does provide methods for dealing with this, have a look at result_metadata function.

I've written a class to allow hassle-free parameterised MySQLi queries - a download and basic usage info is available here: http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=191

Comment: If you're interested, I've created a PDO version using the same interface, so is a drop in replacement for the MySQLi code above. Interestingly, the PDO version seems to run almost 50% quicker than the MySQLi version. Source code is available here: http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=260

Comment: Link broken, answer doesn't contain fix any longer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) and is generally preferred to MySQLi. It offers statements with the regular fetch options, and doesn't force you to explicitly bind all parameters. A typical query might look like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($a));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

PDO is very flexible, so it can be used in other ways as well. There's a lot of great examples in the manual. Take a look!

Comment: nice, PDO looks to be a bit less of a pain than using mysqli for prepared statements :)